# Using my iPad with IOS 7.1.2, how can I sync my calendar from my iPad, iPhone, iPad mini to Google claendar?

Tags: iphone, ipad, data-synchronization, calendar

I realize I can sync my Google calendar to my devices.  However, can someone explain to me in *simple steps* how to get my iPad, iPad mini, and iPhone 5S to return the calendar information to my Google calendar.  I would REALLY appreciate it:)  I have red various preposts similar but most of those questions and answers are about syncing from Google to Apple devices like mine.  Be gentle.  I am a newbie at this site.:)

Answer (score 1):

If you add your Google account in the "Settings" app under "Mail, Contacts, Calendars" the sync works in both directions: Events entered on http://calendar.google.com appear in the iOS calendar app and events saved into the Google calendars on your iPhone/iPad will appear on the Google Calendar website.

However this works only for new events. If you have existing events that you would like to copy into Google Calendar you can use my free app [SyncCal](http://synccal.calengoo.com) ([iTunes Link](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/synccal-free/id1000674065?mt=8)).